# UIRefreshControl for uitableview is not working in only iphone 6

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

Actually this working is fine in all devices except IPhone-6. Please help me for this problem.

my code is

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)


func refresh(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    if self.appDel.isNetworkEnabled
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if(self.page < Int(self.total_pages)! )
            {
                self.page = self.page + 1
                self.fetchMessageApiCall()
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.singletonObj.showAlert("", message: "No Internet")
    }

    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: Add your relevant code for `UIRefreshControl`.

Comment: No one able solve your problem by this one line question.

Comment: for all devices working fine except iphone 6

Comment: self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
            self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)

Comment: func refresh(_ sender:AnyObject) {
        if self.appDel.isNetworkEnabled
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if(self.page < Int(self.total_pages)! )
                {
                    self.page = self.page + 1
                    self.fetchMessageApiCall()
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.singletonObj.showAlert("", message: "No Internet")
        }
        
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }

Comment: Don't put your code in comment, edit your question with code.

Comment: yeah, I understand you can check in body now

Answer (score 2):

May be you should put this `self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()` when your are done fetching data from API.

Answer (score 1):

Just allocate refresh controller like this:

```
    let tableViewControler = UITableViewController()
    tableViewControler.tableView = self.tableView
    self.refreshController = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshController.tintColor = UIColor(red: 87.0/255.0, green: 53.0/255.0, blue: 129.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Refresh")
    self.refreshController.attributedTitle = attributedString
    self.refreshController.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    tableViewControler.refreshControl = self.refreshController
```

hope this helps

Comment: I think same thing only I written.

Comment: @NagarajaGhantasala just use this, I assigns tableView object to `UITableViewController`.

Comment: code is same that is written in body of this question

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3.0**

I faced this issue in IOS 10 and above, and resolved it using below code

```
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self.gigListTableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        self.gigListTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
```